# How to implement LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN to replace NOT IN in hive query?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables in Hive: `empSrc` and `empTrg`:

```
> select * from empSrc;
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--+
| empsrc.empid  | empsrc.dept  |  empsrc.ph  | empsrc.role  |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--+
| e1            | dev          | 9999911111  | SE           |
| e2            | admin        | 6677889933  | SE           |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--+
2 rows selected (0.872 seconds)
> select * from empTrg;
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+--+
| emptrg.empid  | emptrg.dept  |  emptrg.ph  | emptrg.role  | emptrg.dml_action  | emptrg.active  |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+--+
| e1            | dev          | 9999911111  | SE           | I                  | A              |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+--+
```

I want to find the records that are in `empSrc` *but missing* in `empTrg`.
My query is working fine:

```
select S.* from empSrc S
where S.empid not in (select T.empid from empTrg T);
+----------+---------+-------------+---------+--+
| s.empid  | s.dept  |    s.ph     | s.role  |
+----------+---------+-------------+---------+--+
| e2       | admin   | 6677889933  | SE      |
+----------+---------+-------------+---------+--+
```

Problem is that this query is making a cross-product.
Is there any equivalent `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query which I can use ?
Will the LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN help in performance ?
The above scenario is a demo scenario, in actual data I have ~12million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `select S.* from empSrc S
where S.empid not in (select T.empid from empTrg T)` doesn't actually perform a cross join. There is no problem with it.

The same logic can be replicated with `not exists`

```
select s.*
from empSrc s 
where not exists (select 1 from empTrg t where t.empid = s.empid)
```

or a `left join`.

```
select s.*
from empSrc s
left join empTrg t on t.empid = s.empid
where t.empid is null --condition to check for non existent records
```